# how to fix Use of undefined constant SORI_DESC - assumed 'SORI_DESC' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: php

i want to display information from database in descending but its giving me an error

i have tried using the `orderby(['id']=>DESC)->limit(8)->all()`

it  gives me another error .
if i use the `orderBy(['id'])` only it  does not limit the output it displays

```
   public function actionIndex()
    {
    $products =Product::find()->orderBy(['id'=>SORI_DESC])->limit(8)-
    >all();
      return $this->render('index',['products'=>$products]);
    }
```

> Use of undefined constant SORI_DESC - assumed 'SORI_DESC' (this will
>   throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: what framework are you using? Obviously SORI_DESC is NOT a defined constant. Either define one or use a variable or a string instead. But all these depend on what framework you are using. One cannot say for sure without knowing this.

Comment: maybe the constant is SORT_DESC instead of SORI_DESC? Can you try but again it depends on what framework you use

Comment: Im using yii2, i tried SORT__DESC but it still gives me that error..